# Shortcut to file browser when saving files

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, save-as, microsoft-office-2019

Background: I miss the days when Ctrl-S instantly brought up a file browser with a text box at the bottom for a name and a menu below for file type, but for many years it's only been easy if you want to save in OneDrive or one of the last few folders you actually saved things in. (But even that was not so easy, since the most recent folders are always changing.)

Situation: I just started using Office 2019, and noticed that they took half a step in the direction I was hoping - while it's still a choice between OneDrive and a recently used folder, it's now in a separate small window. That inspired a hope that they might have done more as well.

Question: Is there a way to configure Office 2019 so that I can press a keyboard shortcut and instantly see the Save As file browser?

Comment: How about pressing F12?

Comment: Or Alt-F then A?